# why is nav icon not showing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Own Css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Tropico</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Section - 1 Navigation Starts -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""><span>Tropico</span></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navmenu">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#fruits" class="nav-link">Fruits</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#service" class="nav-link">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact us</a>
          </li>
          <button class="nav-item">Get a quote</button>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Section - 1 Navigation End -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nav icon not showing when display goes below 992px as i used navbar-expand-lg in bootstrap5.
Nav icon not showing when display goes below 992px as i used navbar-expand-lg in bootstrap5
Nav icon not showing when display goes below 992px as i used navbar-expand-lg in bootstrap5
Nav icon not showing when display goes below 992px as i used navbar-expand-lg in bootstrap5
Nav icon not showing when display goes below 992px as i used navbar-expand-lg in bootstrap5
Nav icon not showing when display goes below 992px as i used navbar-expand-lg in bootstrap5

Comment: explain more your issue , not getting understand

Answer (score 0):

maybe your source in img tag is wrong
if you have img folder in your root path (based on src="img/logo.png") change it to `<img src="/img/logo.png" alt="">`

If not worked see [html file paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap 5.0.2, you got to do the following modification:

- Add `.navbar-light` in `<nav>` to have the nav burger menu icon displayed. It's because the selector in Bootstrap to display the image is `.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon` so without `.navbar-light` it won't be displayed.

Spotted another issue with the interaction with this toggle icon. You'll need to do the following modifications as well:

- Modify `data-toggle="collapse"` to `data-bs-toggle="collapse"`
- Modify `data-target="#navmenu"` to `data-bs-target="#navmenu"`

FYI `data-target` was the previous annotation used in Bootstrap v4. Now, in Bootstrap v5, every `data-*` has been changed to `data-bs-*`

Don't forget to use `aria-*` as mentioned in Bootstrap documentation as well for accessibility :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some BS missing classes

[image]

try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Own Css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Tropico</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Section - 1 Navigation Starts -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/vhbkAUt.png" width="40" alt=""><span>Tropico</span></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navmenu">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#fruits" class="nav-link">Fruits</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#service" class="nav-link">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact us</a>
                        </li>
                        <button class="nav-item">Get a quote</button>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Section - 1 Navigation End -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```